# Does MMA have a built-in function or a user-defined function to judge whether the two matrices are congruent

Tags: matrix

It can be seen from the following relationship that matrix `A` and matrix `B` must be congruent matrices with each other:

```
A = {{1, 4, 4}, {5, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 3}};
B = EulerMatrix[{π/4, 0, 0}]\[Transpose].A.EulerMatrix[{π/4, 
     0, 0}];
```

But matrix A and matrix B are not real symmetric matrices, so I wonder if there are built-in functions or custom function packages that can determine whether any two matrices(For example, matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}
1 & 4 & 4 \\
5 & 2 & 2 \\
3 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right)$ and matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
6 & 0 & 3 \sqrt{2} \\
1 & -3 & -\sqrt{2} \\
2 \sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2} & 3
\end{array}\right)$) are congruent with each other.

Comment: This seems to be a difficult problem in general and I do not believe that there is a built-in method. Maybe this survey on the topic is helpful: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280932102_Canonical_forms_for_congruence_of_matrices_a_tribute_to_H_W_Turnbull_and_A_C_Aitken